# Can you give me an example of how to train in Python an HMM with customized emission probabilities?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, hidden-markov-models

Basically, I'm reading the documentation https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hmmlearn.base._BaseHMM, and trying to use the _BaseHMM class. But being new to Python, I'm having lot of trouble. Somewhat more generally, I'm trying to verify that an HMM can learn from sequential data and give us more accurate prediction. Toward this direction, I'm considering the case where the algorithm determines the classes of 6 images into 3 classes, and I consider the sample to be ordered or sequenced. Suppose I define the parameters for this HMM. What I'd like to see is the output and the accuracy of this HMM with **custom made emission probabilities**.See the code below, I'm sure I made a basic mistake, but a sample code would be great!

```
import numpy as np
from hmmlearn import hmm

#confusion matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_true = ["cat", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "bird"]
y_pred = ["ant", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "cat"]

C_old= confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=["cat", "ant", "bird"])

model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3, covariance_type="full")
model.startprob_ = np.array([0.333, 0.333, 0.333])
model.transmat_ = np.array([[0.5, 0.5, 0],
                             [0.5, 0, 0.5],
                             [0,   1, 0]])

X=y_true

from hmmlearn import _BaseHMM
hmm._base._BaseHMM._init(X,len(X))
```

I'm getting:

```
ImportError: cannot import name _BaseHMM
```

Note that, I *defined* the emission probability. Now since my emission probabilities are custom-made, it seems I've to use the `class _BaseHMM`. This is where I'm stuck, and I'd really appreciate a sample code using this class and the final confusion matrix after using the HMM. Am using Python 2.7.

Comment: can you show us the entire code rather than a portion of it?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ, just did so. I'm probably making a syntactical or otherwise basic mistake. If you could give me a sample code for my purpose, I'd appreciate it. I'm super new to both Python and HMM. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I will work on this later when I get home. thanks.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ: thank you!

Comment: The class is `hmmlearn.base._BaseHMM` not `hmmlearn._BaseHMM` as you try to import. `from hmmlearn.base import _BaseHMM` should work.